# What is wrong with malloc?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

Even if i allocate 0 byte the program works.Am i doing something wrong ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   char *str;

   printf("memory address of str %p  %p\n",&str,str);
   /* Initial memory allocation */
   str = (char*)malloc(0);

   printf("memory address of str %p  %p\n",&str,str);
   strcpy(str,"abc");
   printf(" string = %s   %p  %p\n", str,&str, str);
   free(str);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "works".

Comment: If your program was guaranteed to crash, that would be *defined behaviour*. But just as your car is not guaranteed to roll away when you leave the parking brake off, and you are not guaranteed to fall over if you don't tie your shoelaces, the result is *undefined*.

Comment: i mean i allocate 0 byte for the string abc

Comment: You've allocated 0 bytes, which means as per the spec you cannot dereference that pointer. However this is not enforced by the compiler. So later copying more than 0 bytes into that memory will not necessarily immediately crash your program. It does mean that your program is in an undefined state and various calls later could crash.

Comment: so the string abc is stored elsewhere ? and not where i wanted it to .

Comment: The C language doesn't having training wheels for beginners. You are responsible for allocating enough memory. And you are responsible for making sure that the code doesn't attempt to access memory that is out-of-bounds.

Comment: Yes, the string is obviously stored *somewhere*. Where that is, is undefined. It could be in some piece of unused memory, or overwriting an important piece of data, or whatever. As others have said, it is *undefined behaviour*. It could cause an immediate crash, or one later, or it could have no (noticeable) effect. Obviously, in your case, it didn't cause an immediate crash. That's all that can be said about this.

Answer (score 2):

From [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) documentation:

> If size is zero, the return value depends on the particular library
>   implementation (it may or may not be a null pointer), but the returned
>   pointer shall not be dereferenced.

[Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) says:

> If the size of the space requested is 0, the behavior is
>   implementation-defined: the value returned shall be either a null
>   pointer or a unique pointer.

That means when size is 0, malloc() returns either NULL or a unique pointer that can be freed afterwards.

Comment: so how do i allocate memory for a string and how will i know if memory is not allocated ?

Comment: a) allocate one more byte than you need (for the `nul` terminator). b) Test the return value. And c) read the man page for `malloc`.

Comment: // allocate memory for a string
`char* str = (char*) malloc(size);`

// to know know if memory is allocated or not
`if(str == NULL)
    return;`

Comment: still it doesnt return

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   char *str;

   printf("memory address of str %p  %p\n",&str,str);
   /* Initial memory allocation */
   str = (char*)malloc(0);
   if(str == NULL) return;
   printf("memory address of str %p  %p\n",&str,str);
   strcpy(str,"abc");
   printf(" string = %s   %p  %p\n", str,&str, str);
   free(str);

   return(0);
}

Comment: it may not always return null pointer. it can return a unique pointer too.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Yes, the thing you are doing wrong is:

```
str = (char*)malloc(0);
strcpy(str,"abc");
```

If you allocate 0 bytes then you are only allowed to store 0 bytes there. Not 4 ('a', 'b', 'c' and the terminating null character).

Allocating some memory means reserving that memory for you, but even if some memory isn't reserved for you, you can sometimes still write to it - like nothing stops you from putting items in someone else's trolley at the supermarket.